# Como empaquetar ficheros doc que estan en el root

Tags: angular5

En angular 5 o 6, ¿Como puedo añadir archivos doc en el root que después al generar 'dist' esten incluidos?

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenid@ a la comunidad.

Angular tiene una carpeta llamada Assets, en la cual puedes incluir todos los archivos que quieras se incluyan.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias,necesito que sea en el root, puedo hacerlo a mano o con scripts externos, pero quería saber si es posible añadirlos a alguna fichero de configuración y no tener que hacer estas labores tediosas

Comment: Existe alguna razón por la que no puedas obtenerlos en el assets?

Comment: Si, dos ficheros son de configuracion del host y han de estar en el root, luego hay imagenes para las apps y cuando se hacen iconos sobre un escritorio, que tambien han de estar en el root